Walks in Nice (Nizza)
Narrative
Recently, I visited Nice (a French city on the Mediterranean coast) and saw a curious tourist wandering through the city. His walk started at the center of the 'Promenade des Anglais'. He stepped in one of the four cardinal directions: north (N), south (S), east (E), and west (W). His walk always ended somewhere at the promenade, but he never stepped into the Mediterranean Sea (in other words, he never ventured south of the promenade).
Definition
Let us define a Nice-walk, consisting of a sequence of n steps, each of which is one of N/S/E/W, such that at each point along the way, the number of N-steps that have been taken is never less than the number of S-steps, and in the end, they are equal (with no restrictions on the distribution of E- or W-steps).
Challenge
Give a function that enumerates the Nice-walks of length n as strings over the alphabet {N, W, E, S} (you might use different symbols). The walks can be given as a comma-separated list or line by line. The order of the walks does not matter. Try to make the code as short as you can. Give evidence by showing the walks for n = 5.
This is code-golf, so each language's shortest code in bytes wins.
Example
These are the Nice-walks of length 4:
NNSS, NSNS, NSEE, NSEW, NSWE, NSWW, NESE, NESW, NWSE, 
NWSW, NEES, NEWS, NWES, NWWS, ENSE, ENSW, WNSE, WNSW, 
ENES, ENWS, WNES, WNWS, EENS, EWNS, WENS, WWNS, WWEE, 
WEWE, WEEW, EWWE, EWEW, EEWW, WWWE, WWEW, WEWW, EWWW, 
EEEW, EEWE, EWEE, WEEE, WWWW, EEEE. 

Credits
Nice-walks are also known in the literature as 'Touchard's Drunkard'. Touchard's identity states that these walks are counted by the Catalan numbers C(n+1) (but not by C(n)!). Nachum Dershowitz studies the relationships in Touchard's Drunkard. I made the narrative a little bit friendlier.

@Arnauld Related yes, but not the number of Nice-walks!

Don't worry, the code is fine, just the comment was off-by-one.

A000108 also calls them Dyck paths.

A039598 is also relevant; it calculates the number of paths ending k steps from the sea. The second formula should make it obvious why (note that there is a typo and it should say a(n, k) = 0 if k<0).

@Neil Not quite. Dyck paths are up-down paths (alphabet {U, D}) and their number is the Catalan numbers. See for example MITedu.

You're right, I misread the comment; it appeared to use two dimensions, but one was irrelevant.

JavaScript (V8), 76 bytes
f=(n,y=1,s='',i=2)=>y*n--?[...'ENWS'].map(c=>f(n,i--%2+y,s+c)):--y||print(s)

Try it online!

JavaScript (V8), 86 bytes
-4 thanks to @l4m2
n=>{for(i=4**n;i--;t||print(s))for(s=t="",j=n;j--;t-=t<0||~-q%2)s+="NESW"[q=i>>j*2&3]}

Try it online!
Commented
n => {                 // n = input
  for(                 // outer loop:
    i = 4 ** n;        //   start with i = 4 ** n
    i--;               //   stop when i = 0
    t || print(s)      //   if t = 0, print s
  )                    //
    for(               //   inner loop:
      s =              //     s = Nice-walk string
      t = "",          //     t = north/south counter
      j = n;           //     start with j = n
      j--;             //     stop when j = 0
      t -=             //     update t:
        t < 0 ||       //       -1 if it's already negative
        ~-q % 2        //       otherwise: +1 for north, -1 for south,
                       //       unchanged for east and west
    )                  //
      s += "NESW"[     //     update s:
        q = i >> j * 2 //       the character index q is obtained by
            & 3        //       extracting the next 2 bits from i
      ]                //       according to j
}                      //


Once t<0, t can only decrease. Shorter

Charcoal, 38 bytes
Ｎθ⊞υωＦυ«≔⁼№ιN№ιSη¿‹ＬιθＦ✂SNWEη⊞υ⁺ικ¿η⟦ι

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
Ｎθ

Input n.
⊞υωＦυ«

Start a breadth-first search for walks of length n.
≔⁼№ιN№ιSη

See if this walk ends at the seaside.
¿‹Ｌιθ

If this walk is not long enough, then...
Ｆ✂SNWEη

... for each valid next step...
⊞υ⁺ικ

... add that step to the walk and add that walk to the search list.
¿η⟦ι

Otherwise if the walk ends at the seaside then output that walk.
By comparison, generating all walks of length n and filtering out those that step into the sea or do not end up at the seaside takes 39 bytes even on ATO and technically does not generate the correct output for n=0 (it outputs nothing instead of a single empty string but you can't tell that the cursor is in the wrong place).

Python3, 156 bytes
C=str.count
def f(n):
 q=['']
 for i in q:
  if len(i)==n:
   if C(i,'N')==C(i,'S'):yield i
  else:
   for j in'NSEW':
    if C(U:=i+j,'N')>=C(U,'S'):q+=[U]

Try it online!

if len(i)<n:q+=[i+j for j in'NSEW'if C(i+j,'N')>=C(i+j,'S')], elif C(i,'N')==C(i,'S'):yield i seems to work; I don't know whether you can walrus that down further.

Receives the unofficial questioner's award.

Nice. Leave out the 'W' in 'NSEW'. And count the solutions. You seem to generate the Motzkin paths A001006. I wonder if this also works for the other answers.

Jelly,  16 15  14 bytes
4ṗµı*ÄḞoṂṪƊµÐḟ

A monadic Link that accepts a non-negative integer and yields a list of the walks as a list of lists of integers:
E  1
N  2
W  3
S  4

Try it online! Or see the test-suite (runs for [0..input]; reformats using ENWS and sorts walks).
How?
4ṗµı*ÄḞoṂṪƊµÐḟ - Link: WalkLength
4ṗ             - four Cartesian power {WalkLength} -> PotentialWalks
  µ        µÐḟ - discard those PotentialWalks for which:
   ı           -   i (square root of -1)
    *          -   exponentiate {PotentialWalk} (vectorises) -> Directions
     Ä         -   cumulative sums {Directions} -> Locations
          Ɗ    -   last three links as a monad - f(Locations):
      Ḟ        -     real part -> DistancesNorth
        Ṃ      -     minimum {DistancesNorth} -> MinDistanceNorth
       o       -     {DistancesNorth} logical OR {MinDistanceNorth} (vectorises)
         Ṫ     -   tail


Python 3.8 (pre-release), 148 bytes
If we accept a comma-separated list of tuples as output, and not only a comma-separated list of strings:
import itertools as i
f=lambda n:[s for s in i.product(*["nsew"]*n)if not(-1 in(l:=[s[:x].count("n")-s[:x].count("s")for x in range(n+1)])or l[-1])]

Try it online!
Explanation
We first generate every possible tuple of length n consisting of one-character strings from "nsew":
[s for s in i.product(*["nsew"]*n)]

We check the number of "n" characters minus the number of "s" characters in each of s[:1], s[:2], ... , s[:n]:
l:=[s[:x].count("n")-s[:x].count("s")for x in range(n+1)]

l contains -1 at the first point where the number of south steps is greater than the number of north steps, if that ever happens. The final item in l is not 0 (i.e. it is True) if the number of north and south steps is unbalanced in the whole tuple. We check that neither of these conditions occurs:
(-1 not in l) and (not l[-1])

which is golfed slightly as:
not(-1 in l or l[-1])


05AB1E, 25 22 bytes
'€ÃIãʒ„ewмÇÈ·<ηO¤_sd`P

Outputs in lowercase.
Try it online.
Explanation:
'€Ã                   '# Push dictionary string "news"
   Iã                  # Cartesian product with the input
     ʒ                 # Filter this list by:
      „ewм             #  Remove all "e"s and "w"
          Ç            #  Convert the characters to codepoint-integers
           È·<         #  IsEven *2 -1 (North is now 1; South is -1)
              η        #  Get the prefixes
               O       #  Sum each prefix
                ¤      #  Get the last sum (without popping the list)
                 _     #  Check whether it equals 0
                       #  (aka there are an equal amount of "n" and "s")
                  s    #  Swap to get the list of cumulative sums again
                   d   #  Check for each whether it's non-negative (>=0)
                       #  (aka for every "s" there should have been at least one
                       #  preceding "n")
                    `  #  Dump all those >=0 checks to the stack
                     P #  Take the product of the stack to verify all are truthy
                       # (after which the filtered list is output implicitly)

See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section How to use the dictionary?) to understand why '€Ã is "news".

Nekomata, 16 bytes
ᵐįŋᵖ{∫ŤlƆž≥}→ᵐɗH

Attempt This Online!
Use ←, ∙, ÷, ¢ (characters code 12, 21, 10, 1 in Nekomata's custom encoding) to represent N, W, S, E respectively.
ᵐįŋᵖ{∫ŤlƆž≥}→ᵐɗH        Take n=4 as an example
ᵐį                  Find an n-tuple of [0,1] and [1,0]
                        One possible result: [[0,1],[1,0],[1,0],[0,1]]
  ŋ                 Optionally negate some elements
                        One possible result: [[0,1],[1,0],[-1,0],[0,-1]]
   ᵖ{      }        Check that:
     ∫                  Cumulative sum
                            [[0,1],[1,0],[-1,0],[0,-1]] -> [[0,1],[1,1],[0,1],[0,0]]
      Ť                 Transpose
                            [[0,1],[1,1],[0,1],[0,0]] -> [[0,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0]]
       l                Last element
                            [[0,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0]] -> [1,1,1,0]
        Ɔ               Split into the last element and the rest
                            [1,1,1,0] -> [1,1,1],0
         ž              Check that the last element is 0
                            [1,1,1],0 passes the check
          ≥             Check that every element in the rest is not less than the last element
                            [1,1,1],0 passes the check
                        So [[0,1],[1,0],[-1,0],[0,-1]] passes the check
            →       Increment each element
                        [[0,1],[1,0],[-1,0],[0,-1]] -> [[1,2],[2,1],[0,1],[1,0]]
             ᵐɗ     Convert each element from decimal digits to a number
                        [[1,2],[2,1],[0,1],[1,0]] -> [12,21,1,10]
               H    Convert to characters
                        [12,21,1,10] -> "←∙¢÷"

By default, Nekomata outputs all valid solutions.

Or 11 bytes if we can output a list of [0,1],[0,-1],[1,0],[-1,0] instead of a string:
ᵐįŋᵖ{∫ŤlƆž≥

Attempt This Online!

Another interesting approach is to find all strings of matching parentheses with length 2n+2, remove the first and last parentheses, and replace each pair of parentheses with a direction. I can't find a short way to do this in Nekomata, but this may be helpful for some other languages.

"I can't find a short way to do this in Nekomata, but this may be helpful for some other languages." I've always felt more languages should have a "generate Dyck words" builtin, for what it's worth...!

R, 121 116 bytes
-5 thanks to @pajonk:

-3: lapply -> Map
-1: \n -> literal newline
-1: all(s>=0)&!s[n] -> !any(s<0,s[n])

Without recursion this time. Funnily enough, it also ended up as 121 bytes.
\(n)Map(\(i,w=i%/%4^(1:n-1)%%4,s=cumsum(Re(1i^w)))if(!any(s<0,s[n]))cat(c("N","E","S","W")[w+1],"
",sep=""),1:4^n-1)

Try it online! (Note- TIO doesn't yet support \ for function.)
Expanded (before edits):
function(n) {
  lapply(
    # for all numbers 1 to 4^n
    1:4^n-1, 
    function(
        i,
        # convert to base 4, as a numeric vector
        w=i%/%4^(1:n-1)%%4,
        # calculate the north-south position at each step
        s=cumsum(Re(1i^w))
      ) {
      # if always on land and ends up at the same point
      if (all(s >= 0) & !s[n])
        # lookup the letters for the directions, concatenate and print
        cat(c("N","E","S","W")[w+1], "\n", sep="")
    }
  )
}


Also -5 bytes.

R, 121 116 92 bytes
-5 thanks to @pajonk:

-3: lapply -> Map
-1: \n -> literal newline
-1: sum(w=="N")-sum(w=="S") -> sum((w=="N")-(w=="S"))

Additional -24 thanks to @pajonk by using 0123 for NESW
f=\(n,w={}){q=sum(Re(1i^w))
if(!n&!q)cat(w,"
",sep="")
if(n&q>=0)Map(\(d)f(n-1,c(w,d)),0:3)}

Attempt This Online!
Expanded:
# recursive function
f <- function(n, w=integer()) {
  # calculate net N-S position: 1i^w converts to complex, Re takes 
  #   N-S component
  q <- sum(Re(1i^w))
  # if at end of walk and at 0 N-S position
  if(!n & !q)
    # then print out the walk
    cat(w,"\n",sep="")
  # if not at end of walk and not in the ocean
  if(n&q>=0)
    # try walking in each direction (recursive case)
    Map(
      function(d) {
        f(n - 1, c(w, d))
      },
      0:3
    )
  }

# recursive function:
f <- function(n, w={}) {
  # net N-S position
  q <- sum(w=="N")-sum(w=="S")
  # if at end of walk and at 0 N-S position
  if(!n & !q)
    # then print out the walk
    cat(w, "\n", sep="")
  # if not at end of walk and not in the ocean
  if(n & q >= 0)
    # then for each direction
    lapply(c("E","N","S","W"),
      # try walking that way
      function(d) f(n - 1, c(w, d))
    )
}


-5 bytes. Also, you may change ENSW to eg. 1:4 and save a bunch on "s.

@pajonk Thanks for the pointers on Map and "\n", I'll remember those. Also, unless I'm missing something, conversion from 1:4 to ENSW would take more bytes than I'd save on quotes?

I meant to return 1:4 as allowed - "strings over the alphabet {N, W, E, S} (you might use different symbols)"

@pajonk Doh, missed that. Thanks!
